# AWS ELB Node status 502

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Not sure what would cause this, but I have an api running on node ELB (nginx) at `https://api.example.com`. I am hosting all my statics at `https://www.example.com`. When my statics make a request to the api, it returns either a 502 Error Bad Gateway or 504 Gateway Timeout. If I hit the same api end point with Postman, I have no issues. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Could be a Cross Origin issue, though I don't think that would result in a 502/504..

Comment: What's weird is the `OPTIONS` preflight request succeeds no problem, even in the browser, its the actual request that fails. It does give a Cross Origin headers error but I think its a red herring caused by the 502/504. I imagine the problem is nginx since I have another environment with a similar dns configuration (not running nginx) which works.